# tsql get fk_key specification

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, ssms

So i need to recreate a bunch of foreign keys. The reason is that i want to add cascade to the key, and to do so I need to drop and recreate the key. Sure I could do it by ssms by rightclicking on the key->modify->and add cascade.
But I have som 100 keys and i would like to do this in a script.

I have an idea that I should be able to invoke the method in ssms that scripts the key to a new query editor, but instead push the resulting script into a variable. drop the existing key. Update the string representation of the key and then execute dynamic sql to create it.

Though i am unable to script the key.
Does anyone know how to do this or is there some other way around?

Answer (score 0):

This [article](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3347/drop-and-recreate-all-foreign-key-constraints-in-sql-server/) by Aaron Bertrand describes exactly this and it is going to do the work for you.

It is dynamically creating the `@create` and the `@drop` sql queries. You will only need to change the create script so that you add `'on delete cascade'` at this part of the `@create` query:

```
FOR XML PATH(N''), TYPE).value(N'.[1]', N'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1, N'') + ') 
ON DELETE CASCADE;'
```

It will drop and recreate every foreign key in every table of your database.

Make sure to check the generated queries before executing them.

You can try a working version [here](http://rextester.com/PHLW17513), the Rextester comes with a schema and some tables already so you can see the results.

Answer (score 0):

I have scripted a foreign key, and use the `sys` tables to get all the details that I need to rebuild the script:

```
SELECT FK.[name]
      --
      ,FK.[delete_referential_action_desc]
      ,FK.[update_referential_action_desc]
      --
      ,KC.[constraint_column_id]
      ,PS.[name]
      ,P.[name]
      ,PTC.[name]
      --
      ,RTS.[name]
      ,RT.[name]
      ,RTC.[name]
FROM [sys].[foreign_keys] FK
INNER JOIN [sys].[objects] P
    ON FK.[parent_object_id] = P.[object_id]
INNER JOIN [sys].[schemas] PS
    ON P.[schema_id] = PS.[schema_id]
INNER JOIN [sys].[foreign_key_columns] KC
    ON FK.[object_id] = KC.[constraint_object_id]
-- parent columns
INNER JOIN [sys].[columns] PTC
    ON P.[object_id] = PTC.[object_id]
    AND KC.[parent_column_id] = PTC.[column_id]
-- referenced table schema, name and columns
INNER JOIN [sys].[objects] RT
    ON KC.[referenced_object_id] = RT.[object_id]
INNER JOIN [sys].[schemas] RTS
    ON RT.[schema_id] = RTS.[schema_id]
INNER JOIN [sys].[columns] RTC
    ON RT.[object_id] = RTC.[object_id]
    AND KC.[referenced_column_id] = RTC.[column_id];
```

This will give me even the schema details of each table. Now, you can use the this T-SQL statement in order to do what you want. Note, I am wrapping this in `CTE` just to make the things more readable. Also, we have second `CTE` in order to handle situations where Foreign Key is composed by multiple columns.

```
WITH DataSource AS
(
    SELECT FK.[name] AS [FK_Name]
          --
          ,FK.[delete_referential_action_desc]
          ,FK.[update_referential_action_desc]
          --
          ,KC.[constraint_column_id] AS [FK_ColumnPos]
          ,PS.[name] AS [PT_SCHEMA_NAME]
          ,P.[name] AS [PT_NAME]
          ,PTC.[name]  AS [PT_COLUMN_NAME]
          --
          ,RTS.[name] AS [RF_SCHEMA_NAME]
          ,RT.[name] AS [RF_NAME]
          ,RTC.[name] AS [RF_COLUMN_NAME]
    FROM [sys].[foreign_keys] FK
    INNER JOIN [sys].[objects] P
        ON FK.[parent_object_id] = P.[object_id]
    INNER JOIN [sys].[schemas] PS
        ON P.[schema_id] = PS.[schema_id]
    INNER JOIN [sys].[foreign_key_columns] KC
        ON FK.[object_id] = KC.[constraint_object_id]
    -- parent columns
    INNER JOIN [sys].[columns] PTC
        ON P.[object_id] = PTC.[object_id]
        AND KC.[parent_column_id] = PTC.[column_id]
    -- referenced table schema, name and columns
    INNER JOIN [sys].[objects] RT
        ON KC.[referenced_object_id] = RT.[object_id]
    INNER JOIN [sys].[schemas] RTS
        ON RT.[schema_id] = RTS.[schema_id]
    INNER JOIN [sys].[columns] RTC
        ON RT.[object_id] = RTC.[object_id]
        AND KC.[referenced_column_id] = RTC.[column_id]
), DataSourcePrecalc AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT 
           [FK_Name]
          ,[delete_referential_action_desc]
          ,[update_referential_action_desc]
          ,[PT_SCHEMA_NAME]
          ,[PT_NAME]
          ,STUFF
          (
                (
                    SELECT ', [' + DS1.[PT_COLUMN_NAME] + ']' 
                    FROM DataSource DS1
                    WHERE DS1.[FK_Name] = DS.[FK_Name]
                        AND DS1.[PT_NAME] = DS.[PT_NAME]
                    ORDER BY DS1.[FK_ColumnPos]
                    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')
                ,1
                ,2
                ,''
          ) AS [PT_COLUMNS]
          ,[RF_SCHEMA_NAME]
          ,[RF_NAME]
          ,STUFF
          (
                (
                    SELECT ', [' + DS2.[RF_COLUMN_NAME] + ']' 
                    FROM DataSource DS2
                    WHERE DS2.[FK_Name] = DS.[FK_Name]
                        AND DS2.[RF_NAME] = DS.[RF_NAME]
                    ORDER BY DS2.[FK_ColumnPos]
                    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')
                ,1
                ,2
                ,''
          ) AS [RT_COLUMNS]
    FROM DataSource DS
)
SELECT 
'
ALTER TABLE [' + [PT_SCHEMA_NAME] + '].[' + [PT_NAME] + '] DROP CONSTRAINT [' + [FK_Name] + '];

ALTER TABLE [' + [PT_SCHEMA_NAME] + '].[' + [PT_NAME] + ']  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [' + [FK_Name] + '] FOREIGN KEY(' + [PT_COLUMNS] + ')
REFERENCES [' + [RF_SCHEMA_NAME] + '].[' + [RF_NAME] + '] (' + [RT_COLUMNS] + ')
ON UPDATE CASCADE
ON DELETE CASCADE;

ALTER TABLE [' + [PT_SCHEMA_NAME] + '].[' + [PT_NAME] + '] CHECK CONSTRAINT [' + [FK_Name] + '];
'
FROM DataSourcePrecalc;
```

Note, here the `CASCADE` values are hard codded. You can add some other logic if you want, use the original ones. What's more important here is the initial query that brings us all the needed details. Having it, you can do whatever you want.